# Application to edit TeX code on my smartphone

Tags: editors, android

I'm thinking of installing an application to edit TeX code on my smartphone with the Android operating system.

Does anyone know any?

I thought I'd ask in another app recommendation site, but I do not think they know the TeX language.

Comment: Use any simple text editor available for Android.